# Deserialize json without name

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I'm Scala na json4s to consume json. To deserialize I'm calling org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse and ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract method.
This is a part of json file:

```
     "": {
        "atribute1": "v1",
        "instanceId": "i",
      },
```

It contains attribute without name.
What should be field name in case class to successfully deserialize attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't parse such json into case class. Unless you do a custom deserializer for it and then you can decide it yourself.

```
import org.json4s.{JValue, CustomSerializer, DefaultFormats}
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s._

case class Outer(value: Inner, other: String)
case class Inner(atribute1: String, instanceId: String)

object Formats extends DefaultFormats {
  val outerSerializer = new CustomSerializer[Outer](implicit format ⇒ (
    { case j: JValue ⇒ Outer(
      (j \ "").extract[Inner],
      (j \ "other").extract[String]
    )},
    { case a: Outer ⇒
      ("" → Extraction.decompose(a.value)) ~
      ("other" → a.other)
    })
  )

  override val customSerializers = List(outerSerializer)
}

implicit val formats = Formats

val json = """
    {
      "": {
        "atribute1": "v1",
        "instanceId": "i",
      },
      "other": "1"
    }
  """

JsonMethods.parse(json).extract[Outer]
```